# How to access otrs 6 community edition web service for rest / soap calls?

Tags: otrs

In web interface I have created new web service, for example "Ticketconnector"
Do I need commercial modules or webservice bult-in ? I don`t understand how to get url path for this service to call it`s methods ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately unable. PHP is single stream, and web script oriented. So RestAPI is only possible realize with apache or any else web server.